# php braintree integration

Tags: php, integration, payment-gateway, braintree

I am trying to integrate the Braintree API into my PHP application. I am new in integrating payment gateway. Please, help me with some example code for Braintree API.

Comment: Braintree supplies a PHP wrapper for their API: http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/docs/php (Lots of examples there)

Answer (score 14):

Here is the code you will absolutely need to get started:

```
require_once 'PATH_TO_BRAINTREE/lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('your_merchant_id');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('your_public_key');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('your_private_key');
```

You can find your merchant ID, public key and private key when you log into your sandbox account by looking under the "Account" menu in the top right, clicking on "My User" then on "API Keys". You can actually just select "PHP" from the language dropdown and then the "Copy" button to get the above code populated correctly with your credentials.

After that I would recommend trying to get a simple transaction created to make sure you have everything working. Take a look at the [quick start example](http://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php#quick_start_example) on the Braintree PHP docs and see if you can run that code (after replacing the Braintree_Configuration and require lines) as is to get a successful transaction.

If you can get that code working I would either move on to your own integration or you can take a look at this [example application](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php_examples) in PHP to get a better idea of what a full integration might look like.

If you're still running into problems feel free to contact Braintree support. The support team responds quickly and can even put you in touch with a developer if you have more technical questions.

Answer (score 4):

Braintree has a whole documentation on PHP Integration:
http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/docs/php

Comment: I have downloaded the Braintree api but i'm confused in the following lines:

Comment: Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('marchent_id');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('your_public_key');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('your_private_key'); how to customise this lines ? marchent_id=sandbox loginid? whaere to set 'your_public_key' and 'your_private_key' thanks for reply

Comment: all those keys shoud be available in your merchant account. I dont have experience with Braintree to tell you exacly where, but i am sure if you email the support they will have an answer

Answer (score 4):

1)Sign up for sandbox account https://www.braintreepayments.com/get-started

2)login to your sandbox account https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com

3)On top menu fiund 'Account'->
 then sub menu 'My user'

4)then on the page at botom you will see Authorization
API Keys  link

5) click api keys link.

6) thats all... Njoy

Answer (score 3):

You can signup for a BrainTree sandbox account at following URL

http://www.braintreepayments.com/gateway/access-form

Once you get the sandbox account, find the merchant id, public key and private key and put them to the configuration.php.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem is that Braintree_Configuration is in a file called ...lib/braintree/configuration.php so when PHP looks for it, it looks for a file called Braintree_Configuration.php and does not find .../lib/Braintree/Configuration.php so the examples do not work.

In my case this may be related to Yii and how Yii links in files for debugging but it still does not work...looking for answers...

Answer (score 2):

OK. In my case, I renamed the folder "lib" into "library". Then I spent dozen minutes until I rename the folder name back to "lib", everything works again.

I can't figure out what kind of horseshit that is, it just works.

Basically you just download the library from

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php

Don't touch anything, then things will move along.

Answer (score 2):

The Documentation Available on Braintree developer portal(https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview) is awesome.

If still have some questions and want to find demo example, please check below link for same.

http://www.ilovephp.net/php/simple-braintree-paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-php-with-demo-examples/

If want to integrate Braintree API with 3D secure option check above link.